# Whatever the data available in previous record it should add to the new record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Thanks in advance for answer my question.
Assume I have a table like t1. There are 3 columns in the table.

```
t1.id       t1.ins_dt           base_id
10000       2024-03-27 00:00:00 1234/45678/000/00
10000       2024-03-27 06:30:00 1234/45678/001/00
10000       2024-03-27 09:30:00 1234/45678/002/00
```

I have another table like t2.

```
t2.id    t2.ins_dt              t2.cv
10000    2024-03-27 00:00:00    OD
10000    2024-03-27 00:00:00    TP
10000    2024-03-27 06:30:00    PA
```

If I join these two tables I want the output like,

```
t1.id     t1.base_id           t2.cv
10000     1234/45678/000/00    OD
10000     1234/45678/000/00    TP
10000     1234/45678/001/00    OD
10000     1234/45678/001/00    TP
10000     1234/45678/001/00    PA
10000     1234/45678/002/00    OD
10000     1234/45678/002/00    TP
10000     1234/45678/002/00    PA
```

Comment: What are the criteria for joining the tables? `t2` has no entry for `09:30:00`. Therefore, if you are joining by `id` and `ins_dt`, there should be no record for `base_id = 1234/45678/002/00` in the output. If you are joining only on `id`, there should be 9 records in the output, but you have only 8. Can you explain the logic?

Answer (score 0):

Just inferring from the sample data. Join t1 to t2 on id, for each t2.ins_dt on or earlier than t1.ins_dt.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/It5hFkbh

```
select t1.id,
       t1.base_id,
       t2.cv
  from t1
 inner
  join t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
   and t1.ins_dt >= t2.ins_dt
 order
    by t1.ins_dt,
       t2.cv;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select   t1.id, t1.base_id, t2.cv
from     t1, t2
where    t1.id = t2.id
     and t1.ins_dt >= t2.ins_dt
order by t1.ins_dt, t2.cv;
```